# Get WPF control height when it is set 'Auto'

Tags: c#, wpf, height, controls

I need get a WPF control height for calculate my next control margin top, but when I try get control height with `textbox1.height`, this is return 'Auto' and not numbers

What can I do for get control height, when it is set 'Auto'?

Comment: textbox1.ActualHeight?

Comment: just make sure when you query for `textBox1.ActualHeight`, you do it once the control is `Loaded`. You're going to get 0.0 if you check `ActualHeight` before it's setup properly.

Comment: I don't believe.... is so easy!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome ;-). I had the same problem some time ago ;-).

Comment: @WojciechKulik Post as the answer so it can be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try this:

```
textBox1.ActualHeight
```

Remarks (by @Viv)

> just make sure when you query for textBox1.ActualHeight, you do it once the control is Loaded. You're going to get 0.0 if you check ActualHeight before it's setup properly